# Select all rows with multiple occurrences

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have a single MySQL table with the name 'test' and 3 columns.

```
 ID | playername | lastloginip  
-----------------------------
 1  | user 1     |     1  
 2  | user 2     |     2  
 3  | user 3     |     3  
 4  | user 4     |     4  
 5  | user 5     |     5  
 6  | user 6     |     1  
 7  | user 7     |     1  
 8  | user 8     |     2
```

Now, I would like to `select ALL` the rows where the lastloginip is found multiple times in the table, and then give the count of those rows.

In this case, it should return the number 5
as user 1, 2, 6, 7 and 8 have a lastloginip that is found multiple times.

I already tried using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM test 
    GROUP BY lastloginip 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)  t
```

But that gave back the number 2 instead of 5.
I am not sure how to set up this query correctly. Most of my findings on the internet keep showing only 2 rows or giving the number 2 instead of 5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First `COUNT()`, then `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(occurences) 
FROM 
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS occurences
   FROM test
   GROUP BY lastloginip
   HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) t
```

Comment: Thanks i think i have it now. I changed your first 'misunderstood' version of your query to something that works.  SELECT SUM(occurrences) FROM(
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS occurrences
FROM test
GROUP BY lastloginip
HAVING COUNT(ID)>1) t

Comment: I have a feeling I might have done something silly. Hopefully someone else can have a look at my answer and correct it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT SUM(loginip) 
FROM(
    SELECT 
    lastloginip, 
    COUNT(lastloginip) 
    as loginip 
    FROM test 
    GROUP BY lastloginip 
    HAVING COUNT(ID)>1
)t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the sum of occurrences using the above code and if you want to view the records with multiple occurences, refer to the query below-

> Select *
> from test
> where lastloginip in (
> select *
> from
> (select lastloginip
> from test
> group by lastloginip
> having count(lastloginip)>1
> )
> as a)